# Get cookies synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I know that electron is working on promisifying their api calls, but I think I found a solution in the meantime however, it's not quite working.

In my create window function I have the following...

```
const mainSession = mainWindow.webContents.session
const getCookies = util.promisify(mainSession.cookies.get)
const cookies = await getCookies({})
console.log(cookies)
```

I believe that it's destroying the object before the promise resolves based on this error I get.

```
 (node:21863) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Object has been destroyed
```

The reason I need cookies synchronously is because I'm building a login method for my [canvasFileSync](https://github.com/drew-royster/canvasFileSync) app to generate a long term access token(to authenticate syncing). The method has to be dynamic enough to work for any school's login page where it will essentially 'keep trying' to make the long term access token until it succeeds.

I think you can imagine that making this synchronous would really simplify the process.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Added all relevant code

```
const electron = require('electron')
const util = require('util')
const _ = require('lodash')
const request = require('request-promise')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let mainWindow

async function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})


  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL('https://suu.instructure.com')

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })

  try {
    const mainSession = mainWindow.webContents.session
    const getCookies = util.promisify(mainSession.cookies.get)
    const cookies = await getCookies({})
    console.log(cookies)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Comment: `await` is NOT synchronous.  You sort of get to program it with synchronous looking code, but it's not synchronous.  While it's awaiting, the host function returns and other code runs.  It's asynchronous, just a different way to program asynchronously.

Comment: When using `await`, somebody has to catch errors, either with a `.catch()` on the return value from the containing function or with a `try/catch` around the `await`.  You'd have to show us more of your code for us to be able to identify exactly what you should do and where this error is coming from.

Comment: Thanks! I just added relevant code. I guess the real question I'm looking to ask is how should I handle synchronously grabbing cookies in electron?